# How to index with a DateTimeIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a dataframe called `news` with dates as the row index
`news = news.set_index('Date')`
and a couple of time objects created as such:

```
#create useful date objects
offset = pd.tseries.offsets.Day(n=-10)
today = pd.to_datetime('today').date()
ten_days_ago = (today+offset).date()
last_ten_days = pd.date_range(start=ten_days_ago, end=today)
```

I want to be able to get all of the rows from the last 10 days by indexing like so:
`news[last_ten_days]`
but that does not work.

So far the solution I have is:
`news[str(ten_days_ago):str(today)]`
but this seems like a bad way to do it. Is there any other/better way to do this?

Helpful info: `print(news.head())` prints

```
                                                        Title                                            Summary
Date                                                                                                            
2019-03-26  Walmart to participate in the Cowen and Compan...  Walmart Inc. (NYSE: WMT) will participate in t...
2019-03-26  Attention Entrepreneurs: Walmart Is Now Accept...  Company invites entrepreneurs to pitch new, ni...
2019-03-27                             Walmart's AI Advantage  AI technology is becoming increasing important...
2019-03-28  Walmart Announces 2019 Annual Shareholders' Me...  Formal Business Meeting for Shareholders on Ju...
2019-03-28  A Home in Bloom: Drew Barrymore and Walmart La...  Walmart and Drew Barrymore announced today the...
```

Comment: why it's bad? I think it's quite straight.

Comment: if your index is a `DatetimeIndex` you should be able to just to `news = news[three_days_ago:today]` with out using `str()`.